# Delete rows where two values match, mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to all but one rows that contain the same data, the issue is the data is in multiple fields.

```
|id | ValA | ValB  |
|1  | abc  | abc   |
|2  | abc  | abc   |
|3  | abc  | def   |
```

In the example table above i would want to delete the row with the ID 2, and kept 1 and 3.

The only solution I can find is using loops in PHP but I have 1.7 million records so I do not what to loop though all of these values.

I think the "SQL-way" will be sub querys but i cant work them out

Thanks

Comment: do a group by query and save into a temporary table, then clear your exiting table and load the temp table

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,vala CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,valb CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1  ,'abc','abc'),
(2  ,'abc','abc'),
(3  ,'abc','def');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+------+
| id | vala | valb |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | abc  | abc  |
|  2 | abc  | abc  |
|  3 | abc  | def  |
+----+------+------+


SELECT * 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.vala = x.vala 
   AND y.valb = x.valb 
   AND y.id < x.id;
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | vala | valb | id   | vala | valb |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | abc  | abc  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | abc  | abc  |    1 | abc  | abc  |
|  3 | abc  | def  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.vala = x.vala 
   AND y.valb = x.valb 
   AND y.id < x.id 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
+----+------+------+
| id | vala | valb |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | abc  | abc  |
|  3 | abc  | def  |
+----+------+------+

SELECT x.*  
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.vala = x.vala 
   AND y.valb = x.valb 
   AND y.id < x.id;
+----+------+------+
| id | vala | valb | 
+----+------+------+
|  2 | abc  | abc  | 
+----+------+------+

DELETE x 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.vala = x.vala 
   AND y.valb = x.valb 
   AND y.id < x.id;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+------+
| id | vala | valb |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | abc  | abc  |
|  3 | abc  | def  |
+----+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM 'mytable' t1
  JOIN 'mytable' t2 ON (t1.ValA = t2.ValA) AND (t1.ValB = t2.ValB)
WHERE t1.id > t2.id
```